# How to validate form fields and post the form data to server using JQuery and Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate form fields like, Name (must not be blank), Email_id(must be valid), Mobile(Must be valid). After the filling the all info I have to send this information to server, and redirect response to different page. **Here nothing is working**,

**my form.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="scheduleLaterForm" name="scheduleLaterForm">
    <div class="col-lg-8">      
        <div class="fieldgroup">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" for="userName">Name:<font
                style="color: red;">*</font></label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <input style=" height: 30px;" class="form-control" id="userName" name="userName"
                    placeholder="Full Name" value="" type="text" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fieldgroup">
            <label for="email" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:<font
                style="color: red;">*</font></label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <input style="height: 30px;" class="form-control" name="email"
                    id="email" placeholder="you@example.com" value=""
                    type="text" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fieldgroup">
            <label for="userContactNumber" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Mobile:<font
                style="color: red;">*</font></label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <input style="height: 30px; width:100%;" class="form-control" id="userContactNumber"
                    name="userContactNumber" placeholder="Mobile Number"
                    onkeypress="enableKeys(event);" maxlength="10" type="text" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fieldgroup">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" id="btnBooking" class="submit">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>                                  
</form>
```

**script for validating form and sending data**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#scheduleLaterForm").validate({
            rules: {
                userName: "required",                           
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },                                              
                userContactNumber: "required"                       
            },
            messages: {
                userName: "Please enter your Name",
                userContactNumber: "Please enter your Mobile number",                           
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",                                           
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                // get values from textboxs 
                var uName = $('#userName').val();
                var mailId = $('#addressemailId').val();
                var mobNum = $('#userContactNumber').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url:"http://localhost/services/bookService4Homes.php",
                    type:"GET",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{type:"booking",Name:uName, Email:mailId, Mob_Num:mobNum },
                    //type: should be same in server code, otherwise code will not run
                    ContentType:"application/json",
                    success: function(response){
                         alert("success");
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                    },
                    error: function(err){
                         alert("fail");
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                    }
                });
                return false; // block regular submit
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Php code**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');//Should work in Cross Domaim ajax Calling request
mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db("service4homes");
if(isset($_GET['type']))
{
    if($_GET['type']=="booking"){
        $name = $_GET ['Name'];
        $mobile = $_GET ['Mob_Num'];
        $mail = $_GET ['Email'];    

        $query1 = "insert into customer(cust_name, cust_mobile, cust_email) values('$name','$mobile','$mail')";
        $result1=mysql_query($query1);
    }
}
else{
    echo "Invalid format";
}
?>
```

Comment: so you send data on server, get response and how you make redirect?

Comment: @demo, thanks for reply, I have to redirect that response to different page   like after booking form, send back conformation..

Answer (score 0):

- You do not need an external `click` handler because the plugin automatically captures the `click` (of a `type="submit"`) and blocks the submit.
- You need an `input` or `button` in your `form` that is `type="submit"`, otherwise the plugin will not be triggered at all.
- You cannot have an external `.ajax` function while you have `form.submit` within the `submitHandler` of your `.validate()` method.  This means the plugin is trying to submit the form while your click handler is trying to use `ajax`.  They both cannot work at the same time.  [As per docs, any `ajax` belongs inside the `submitHandler`, and it's *"the right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated"*](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler).
- You don't need to check form validity because when you use the built in `submitHandler`, this is also done automatically.
- The jQuery4U code is nothing but complicated junk; everything can be simplified greatly.  It serves no useful purpose other than to cause more confusion to those seeking guidance. It comes from a popular, yet poorly explained, online demo/tutorial by Sam Deering that is linked to/from many places.

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#register-form").validate({
          rules: {
              userName: "required",                           
              email: {
                  required: true,
                  email: true
              },                                              
              userContactNumber: "required"                       
          },
          messages: {
              userName: "Please enter your Name",
              userContactNumber: "Please enter your Mobile number",                           
              email: "Please enter a valid email address",                                           
          },
          submitHandler: function(form) {

              // get values from textboxs 
              var uName = $('#userName').val();
              var mailId = $('#addressemailId').val();
              var mobNum = $('#userContactNumber').val();

              $.ajax({
                  url:"http://192.168.1.11/services/bookService4Homes.php",
                  type:"POST",
                  dataType:"json",
                  data:{type:"booking",Name:uName, Email:mailId, Mob_Num:mobNum },
                  //type: should be same in server code, otherwise code will not run
                  ContentType:"application/json",
                  success: function(response){
                      //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                  },
                  error: function(err){
                      //alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                  }
              });
              return false; // block regular submit
          }
      });

  });
  ```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/mh6cvf2u/**

Comment: thanks for your reply, It is giving alert like Name:neelabh, Email:undefined, Mobile:9022362323, And I also change accoding to you but It is not working..

Comment: @neelabhsingh, YES, as per the comments in the jsFiddle code, the `alert()` is there as a demonstration that ***is*** the proper place to fire the `ajax()` code.  The `ajax()` is only commented out because the jsFiddle cannot do anything meaningful with it.